# Required field validator not working for dropdownlist in repeater control

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, repeater

I have a drop down list in a repeater. I  am trying to add a required field validator to it.

The aspx code is:

```
<asp:Repeater ID="myRepeter" runat="server" OnItemDataBound="myRepeter_ItemDataBound">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:DropDownList ID="ddl_Name" runat="server" DataTextField="value" DataValueField="key" ></asp:DropDownList>                         
        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="rfv_Name" ControlToValidate="ddl_Name" InitialValue="0" runat="server" ErrorMessage="Please select a Name" ValidationGroup="valgrp_Name" ForeColor="Red"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

I also tried the same from code behind:

```
protected void myRepeter_ItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
{
    foreach(RepeaterItem item in myRepeter.Items)
    {
        DropDownList NametList = item.FindControl("ddl_Name") as DropDownList;

        RequiredFieldValidator validator = item.FindControl("rfv_Name") as RequiredFieldValidator;
                    
        validator.ControlToValidate = NametList .ID;
        validator.ValidationGroup = "valgrp_Name";
    }
}
```

How can I add the required field validator?

Comment: It's a while for me but there no `CausesValidation="true"` on the DropDownList.  Please try that and let me know.

Answer (score 0):

Why are you looping through your repeater inside the databound event? It will automatically loop. Try using e.Item.FindControl instead.

```
                 DropDownList NametList = e.Item.FindControl("ddl_Name") as DropDownList;

            RequiredFieldValidator validator = e.Item.FindControl("rfv_Name") as RequiredFieldValidator;

            validator.ControlToValidate = NametList.ID;
            validator.ValidationGroup = "valgrp_Name";
```

Comment: Still not working

Comment: did you enable it?  validator.Enabled = true;